# CKEditor React Image Resize Plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor5-react

How to use ImageResize with react. I can't find any sample.
I want to resize image which I add from CKEditor on my react component.

```
<CKEditor editor={ClassicEditor}
      data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
      onInit={editor => {
        editor.plugins.get(
          "FileRepository"
        ).createUploadAdapter = loader => {
          return new UploadAdapter(loader)
        }

        //editor.plugins.add("ImageResize") or something?

        console.log("Editor is ready to use!", editor)
      }}
      onChange={(event, editor) => {
        const data = editor.getData()
        console.log({ event, editor, data })
      }}
      onBlur={(event, editor) => {
        console.log("Blur.", editor)
      }}
      onFocus={(event, editor) => {
        console.log("Focus.", editor)
      }}
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the one and correct way to do this is you should fork the ClassicEditor and build your own ClassicEditor.

You can follow this to create your own 
build https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/development/custom-builds.html

After you done with custom your own build, you need to install it from your repository url.

I'm already had a simple custom build that include ImageResize and Base64Uploader in case you want an example:
https://github.com/hmtri1011/ckeditor5-build-classic/blob/stable/src/ckeditor.js

Answer (score 0):

editor.plugins has a method `init( plugins, [ removePlugins ] ) → Promise.<LoadedPlugins>` that initializes a set of plugins and adds them to the collection.

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_plugincollection-PluginCollection.html

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the react component

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information on the [docs page of react](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html#customizing-the-builds):

> While you can change the configuration easily by using the config property of the `<CKEditor>` component which allows you to change the toolbar or remove some plugins, **in order to add plugins you need to rebuild the editor**.

There is full explanation on how to do this in the above link.

Once you have it, you can import `ImageResize` from the `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageresize`:

```
import ImageResize from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageresize";
```

And use it inside your CKEditor's config:

```
<CKEditor
    config={{ plugins: [ImageResize] }}
    ....
/>
```

Comment: CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules: Some CKEditor 5 modules are duplicated. Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules

Comment: @BurakKalafat I'm not sure why is this comment related to my answer. Can you please explain?

Comment: I am getting this error after adding this import and config. It says duplicated modules.

Comment: You will need to re-build the editor. Did you do that? Note that you can't just use the `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic`.

Comment: dont mix build package with other otherwise you will get  ckeditor-duplicated-modules error